# uncheck item is not working when using Set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using Set data structure for toggling the checkbox. For now, the check is working but uncheck is not working. When checking, I am sending the key/id of the item that is selected and when unchecking I tried to delete that key but its converting the whole `checked` state to boolean value. Instead, it should give me the value of checked state as `{'key1', 'key2'}` excluding 'key3' because the item of key3 is unchecked. The Set of immutable.js used to work but not in native javascript.

Here is what I have done

```
class DeviceHome extends React.Component<propsCheck> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { checked: new Set(), group: '' };
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    try {
      if (!nextProps.activeGroup.equals(this.props.activeGroup)) {
        this.setState({ checked: new Set() });
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  toggle(key) {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      checked: checked.has(key) ? checked.delete(key) : checked.add(key),
    });
  }

  toggleAll() {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      checked: checked.size === 0 ? checked.values(this.props.devices) : checked.clear(),
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    console.log('checked', checked, typeof checked);
    const indeterminate = Boolean(checked.size) && checked.size < Object.keys(this.props.devices).length;
    const devices = Object.entries(this.props.devices).map(([key, value]) => {
      const { name, connection_timeout: connectionTimeout } = value;
      return (
        <Table.Row key={key} active={checked.has(key) || false}>
          <Table.Cell>
            <Checkbox checked={checked.has(key)} onChange={() => this.toggle(key)} />
          </Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
      )
    });
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Table unstackable structured>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.HeaderCell>
            <Checkbox
              onChange={() => this.toggleAll()}
              indeterminate={indeterminate}
              checked={
                Boolean(checked.size) &&
                checked.size === Object.keys(this.props.devices).length
              }
            />
          </Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Body>{devices}</Table.Body>
        </Table>
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

Only clear/uncheck part does not work because it changes the data structure to boolean.

Comment: `checked.has(key) ? checked.delete(key) : checked.add(key)` that does not work, do `checked:
 (checked.delete(key) || checked.add(key)) && checked)`

Comment: yes that did work. Thanks a lot. Can you give the answer for this with a bit of explanation, please ? I want to mark this as solved and also  toggleAll is not working so I need to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To really achieve statefulness with Sets you have to completely clone them, then you can mutate it and call setState:

```
 toggle(key) {
   this.setState(({ checked: previous }) => {
     const checked = new Set(previous);
     if(!checked.delete(key)) checked.add(key);
     return { checked };
  });
 }
```

Yours did not work because `delete` returns a boolean, not a Set.